# Changing localhost port in VS Code

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

My 2 main folders are CMS and nextjs as shown below:

[image]

But when I go to run 1 folder it uses my localhost:3000 then the other also wants to use the same port but this is not possible as I get an error saying port 3000 already in use.
Basically I want to run my CMS folder and nextjs folder in 2 different ports.

I have attached my launch.json code just incase:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\nextjs\\.next\\server\\pages\\index.js"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What is your CMS ?

Comment: CMS is where I store my strapi resources and nextjs is where I have my screens and where I call my apis

Comment: Check my updated answer for Strapi below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Next.js

You have to edit the `package.json`.
In the script object you'll find a property named **dev**. You can edit it like this (ex: port 3005) :

`"dev": "next dev -p 3005"`

When you will launch `npm run dev`, you app will turn on port **3005**

### Strapi

Add a `.env` file at the root of your project and add a variable with the port you want:

```
PORT=3627
```

Read more in the Strapi documentation [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#customization-options)